# How to apply 2 conditions with the flow and create the list of approvers?

Tags: list, power-automate, powerapp, approval-process, powerapps-forms

I have two lists, one gets the submitted information from PowerApps and the other one is more like a matrix, to identify the people who are assigned as approvers.
Identification process starts with country level (in different countries, I have different country managers, hence different people are assigned), besides the country level difference, I also have department level. Each department has its own manager.

The flow is triggered by creation of an item in the first list and then I need to get proper approvers, on a country and department level.

For example, if I have in a countries list United Kingdom and France, I have  IT and Marketing departments in each of the countries. And different people are assigned as managers in different countries & departments, hence I have 6 different person (2 -Country manager; 4- Department head)

**I need to identify the right one for the approvers list**.

*Things I have done*:
Countries - in Rows
Departments - in Columns
And I could not create variable that would identify the right department and country to find right person for approval.
I have also thought about creating different entries for different departments, but in this case, list of countries would not be distinct.
This is my first Microsoft flow, it is a little bit tricky and I honestly could not find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your requirement it looks like you need 2 levels of approval.

1. Country Manager
2. Department Manager

For that,
In SharePoint-

1. Create a country master list where you'll keep the Manager column as well and map the manager according to country.
   i.e 1. UK - John Olsen 2. USA - Mike Henry
2. Create Department List and keep the country name as lookup in this list and also a Manager column to maintain Department Manager.
   i.e. - IT Department - UK - Ron Williams
3. Create the items list where you'll store your information and also keep Country and Department columns as lookup columns in that list.

In Power Automate -

1. Get the country item (Use Get Item Trigger) to get the country item and provide the CountryID lookup value in the ID field.
2. Get the department item (Use Get Item Trigger) to get the department item and provide the DepartmentID lookup value in the ID field.
3. For first level assignment, use the Manager column value from Country item and update your current item's assignedTo column according to the manager claims value.
4. For second level assignment, do the same and use the department manager instead.

Hope it solves your query.